# What happens to a one-sided limit for $f(x^2)$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

The specific problem is:
$\lim\limits_{x \to -1^-} f(x^2)$

My  so far attempting a substitution method:
$$x\to -1^-$$
$$u = x^2$$
$$u\to 1^\text{not sure what  this is now}$$

I can't really use the method to solve this, yet, since my underlying  is unresolved: how does the $x^2$ affect the left direction of the limit?

Additionally, is there a better  to solve this? After evaluating the $u\to 1^c$  (c is either + or - aka left or ) I was planning to then substitute like this:

$$\lim_{u \to 1^c} f(u)$$

Comment: Hint: Can you draw a graph for $f(x^2)$?

Comment: HInt :example for $$(-1)^{-}$$ is $-1.001$,example for $$(-1)^{+}$$ is $-0.999$

Comment: @kishlaya I don't think so...I can draw points for f(x^2) when x = -1, 0, 1, and easy points, but then if I did -1.001 that's f(1.002001) which is somewhere between 0 and 1 according to the graph, but we don't know for sure.

Comment: @K_7 what you have there is a demonstration (not a full proof, but it can be made into one with only minor modifications) of the fact that when $x$ closes in on $-1$ from the left, $x^2$ closes in on $1$ from the right.

Comment: Since $u=x^{2}\to 1^{+}$ as $x\to - 1^{-}$ you can easily see that the desired limit is $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The answer key provided by the teacher says its 2.

Comment: In mathematics it is very common that answer keys are wrong.dont worry the correct answer is $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Asked my teacher today...she said the answer is 2 because you square the -1 to get 1, and then look at 1 from the left. In other words, she says to ignore the limit direction until after applying the function, and then use the original direction.

Comment: You can't ignore the direction (otherwise there is no need of that notation in limit). When $x\to - 1^{-}$ then $x<-1$ and therefore $u=x^{2}>1$ and $u\to 1^{+}$. The accepted answer also says the same thing. "argument by authority" is easiest to beat when the argument is mathematical. I must say your teacher is wrong here. And you should be able to convince her about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\to a^-$ means, that $x$ is approaching $a$ on the valueas that are smaller than $a$.

So if $x\to y=a-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon \to 0^+$ ($\epsilon \geq 0$), then

$x^2 \to y^2 = (a-\epsilon)^2 = a^2 -2 a\epsilon +\epsilon^2$.

Since $a\leq 0$, we have

$-2 a\epsilon\geq 0$,

thus

$a^2 -2 a\epsilon +\epsilon^2 \geq a^2$

so for $a\leq 0$ we have 
$$x^2 \to (a^2)^+$$

**EDIT**

I've been thinking about simplier eplaination.

If $i\leq j\leq0$, then $0\leq j^2 \leq i^2$.

In our case we have $x\leq -1$, so $1\leq x^2$. Thus $x^2\to 1^+$

Comment: Do you think it's important to understand the proof for this? Or is it sufficient to simply generalize that a left-side limit will become a right-side limit through squaring?

Comment: @K_7 Well. Actually the most important thing to understand there is that if $i<j<0$, then $0<j^2<i^2$

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks.